# How to store a value retrieved from a request that runs in loop into a variable and use it later in jmeter

Tags: arrays, loops, jmeter

I want to create an object in loop in JMeter which returns unique id each time it's created. Later I want to store the id of each object created in an array and want to read the values from array to use it in the next request. Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to go for [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) scripting in any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), example code would be something like:

```
def number_of_loops = 5
def array = []

1.upto(number_of_loops, {
    array.add(UUID.randomUUID())
})

vars.put('array', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(array).toPrettyString())
```

Generated array will be stored in the `${array}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)